# Open a modal dialog box, containing dynamic data on table cell click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve as the title suggests. Currently I can display the contents of a `<div>` using:

```
document.write("<table><tr>");
...
document.write("<td onclick=\"window.location.href='#popup'\" ... >" + name + "\"</td>);
```

With the `<div>` defined as: (where I'm trying to use `data-name`)

```
<div id="popup" data-name="name" class="dialog">

    <a href="#close"><img src="..." alt="..." width="166" height="104" align="left" /></a>
    <p>                
        Hello (dynamic name here)!     
    </p>            
</div>
```

I have tried instead calling:

```
document.write("<td onclick=\"popup(" + name + ")\" class=\"programme\">" + name + "</td>");

function popup(movieName)
{
    var pop = document.getElementById("popup"); 
    pop.setAttribute("data-movie", movieName);

    document.location.href = "#popup";
};
```

but I no longer see the popup this way.

I would eventually want to "popup" to be a modal dialogue window which will display on top of the table. Currently as it's defined above the table it just pushes the table down when displayed.

**Edit:** Thanks for the fantasic help. Both @carlosHT and @TimeDead. Both solutions work and both taught me a lot. I've gone for carlosHT's solution as it's a smaller implementation. The only addition I had to add was:

```
.ui-dialog
{
    clear: both;
}
```

This stops the dialog window from having a very tall titlebar.

Comment: I highly recommend jQuery-UI's Dialog.  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: @HowardRenollet Ok thanks. Would this be suitable even if I wasn't entering the data in myself? Just displaying already existing data? Which `name` is displayed is dependent on which table cell is clicked.

Comment: Absolutely!  I use it all the time for dynamic server-side data that I've retrieved from the server via AJAX.  Seriously worth looking into :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative using jQuery and jQueryUI:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            #popup{
                display: none;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            .cell-which-triggers-popup{
                cursor: pointer;    
            }

            .cell-which-triggers-popup:hover{
                background-color: yellow;    
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="popup" class="dialog">
            <a href="#close"><img src="http://bit.ly/1qAuZh3" alt="..." width="166" height="104" align="left"/></a>
            <p></p>            
        </div>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="cell-which-triggers-popup">exampleName</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".cell-which-triggers-popup", function(event){
        var cell_value = $(event.target).text();
        showPopup(cell_value)    
    });

    function showPopup(your_variable){
        $("#popup").dialog({
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            open: function(){
                $(this).find("p").html("Hello " + your_variable)
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/xaqtawog/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response and the jsfiddle link! Your code does work yes. I have added a simple table to your example. I am hoping to be able to click the name of the cell to display the modal window with the cells name as `showPopup`'s input variable. Even better to be able to click anywhere in the cell! Which is my current implementation minus `your_variable`. 

http://jsfiddle.net/90hrnkbm/2/

Comment: DropTheTable, I've updated the answer with what I think you're looking for. In this case, instead of using the button as the trigger for the popup, you can use the "td" element itself by referencing it through the "cell-which-triggers-popup" class. I've updated the fiddle as well.

Comment: Trying to implement this. It works in jsfiddle but getting this error incorporating it into my project:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#popup").dialog') (21:47:52:428 | error, javascript)

using the simple table seen in the jsfiddle

Comment: You're probably lacking the script tags referencing jQueryUI on your html page. Make sure you have a reference for the CSS stylesheet and for javascript file.

Comment: Ah I thought it did, but I didn't. Progress! Oddly the popup window had a very large grey top section which contains the close button. Also it still isn't working in my main `<table>` but I'm guessing that has something to do with its .css attributes or the fact that I write the table using `document.write(..."

Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, the fact that it doesn't work on your table, considering that you're doing the whole document.write thing like you said, could be because the event listener is not being attached to your cell due to the fact that the cell does not exist yet when the attempt to attach the listener happens. To avoid that you can use something like $(document).on("click", ".cell-which-triggers-popup", function(event). I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: The $(document).on thing will basically attach the listener to any element with the "cell-which-triggers-popup" class independently of when they are inserted into the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this also without jQuery-UI (as it did not work for me at the time though I am slowly changing over to it)

You can achieve a functioning modal with jQuery, and JS like so:
(Call your css from an external file to style the modal)

Setup a function literal in a file:

```
(function($) {

 }(jQuery)
```

Inside our fucntion literal we will have it build our modal (This also has JS add in the CSS which you can manually set anywhere this is for the sake of example)

setup the default parameters and execute our other builder functions:

```
$.fn.siteModal = function(prop) {
options = $.extend({
            height: "500",
            width: "500",
            title: "default modal box",
            description: "This is a place holder Modal to put in our things into.",
            top: "20%",
            left: "30%",
        }, prop);

    };  
return(
            add_block_page(),
            add_popup_box(),

            $('.modalBox').fadeIn()
        );

        return this;
    };
```

This guy here is going to setup some default parameters that our modal is going to use so it knows what size and how to display.

Now we setup our builder functions

```
function add_block_page() {
        var block_page = $('<div class="blockPage"></div>');

        $(block_page).appendTo('body');
    }
```

this guy here is going to create a new div that will create a lightly transparent black overlay on the webpage for our modals background and then append it to the body so it can be displayed.

Now we are going to add the popup modal itself:

```
function add_popup_box() {
        var pop_up = $('<div class="modalBox"><a href="#" class="closeModal">X</a><div class="innerModal"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div></div>');
        $(pop_up).appendTo('.blockPage');

        $('.closeModal').click(function() {
            $('.blockPage').fadeOut().remove();
            $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
        });
    }
```

This guy is going to create our divs for the modal (an outer and then an inner div the inner will contain our content) this also setups our X button so that when you click X the modal will close out and bring you back to the webpage correctly.

My HTML looks a little like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.fn.siteModal(this)" class="termsLink">Terms</a>
```

So now when the "terms" link is clicked a new modal will open up! (this is how I call the modal for now)

This is a very basic way to do it, and once again you have to build your styles inside an external css if you'd like or you can have jquery add css as it builds this modal. The choice is yours. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I have a CSS function that creates the look for our modal box you can throw this guy in there:

```
function add_styles() {
        /*Block page overlay*/
        var pageHeight = $(document).height();
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();

        $('.blockPage').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0',
            'left': '0',
            'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
            'height': pageHeight,
            'width': pageWidth,
            'z-index': '10'
        });

        $('.modalBox').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'left': options.left,
            'top': options.top,
            'display': 'none',
            'height': options.height + 'px',
            'width': options.width + 'px',
            'border': '1px solid #fff',
            'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            'border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            'background': '#f2f2f2',
            'z-index': '50',
        });
        $('.innerModal').css({
            'background-color': '#fff',
            'height': (options.height - 50) + 'px',
            'width': (options.width - 50) + 'px',
            'padding': '10px',
            'margin': '15px',
            'border-radius': '10px',
            'color' : '#5a5a5a',
            'text-align' : 'center',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px'
        });
    }
```

And put this into your calls at the prop function: `add_styles()`

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I've tried testing out your example. Correct me if I'm wrong as I'm new to Javascript but is your `function(prop, el)` correct? Cheers

Comment: Oh I'm terribly sorry it should just be prop, I have el in there for my script uses because I have element selection going on in my site. I think if you pull out el it should be okay.

Comment: It was my return silly me overlooked it when I was ripping the code out of my setup I had a few bracket errors. I fixed it in this Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubun1Lba/ I also added external css for the closemodal button. Hope you enjoy.

Comment: I am very close to a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ubun1Lba/1/

All I need now is to be able to pass the cell text content to the modal window to display it. Would this be achievable by adding a parameter to `siteModal(this)` I had a look at `$.extend` which can take up to 2 more object parameters.

Comment: In this jsFiddle I added an if statement with new options to our setup, and then I added a class to your html link. this allows the function to determine what kind of modal to open with your own content. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ubun1Lba/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64654/discussion-between-timedead-and-dropthetable).